# Maximo Rest API: Filter on child table in the OS

Tags: maximo

I've setup and Object structure to be used as the endpoint for my rest service and have a couple of questions.

This service is leveraging the Shift logging module.  it logs entries per day with the SHIFTLOG table being created for the day and then LOGENTRIES are created for each log that needs to happen over the course of the day for that shift.  I've tried to pull the Log entry separately with no success.  Really the only way to pull it is with the Shiftlog table being the primary on the OS and logentry as the child.

I've posted the request endpoint below with the . notation in order to use the where clause on the logtype attribute.  I'm no longer getting an invalid error but it is also not actually filtering based on the attribute provided.  Same for the the date range below.

```
{{domainAPI}}os/LOGENTRY?lean=1&oslc.select=shiftnum, PLUSGSHFTLOGENTRY{recordkey, logtype, OID_CUST, LOGTEXT_CUST, EVENTDATE, RTNDATE_CUST, description, location, locationsid, controlroom, logtext_gre, notes_CUST, outagetype_CUST}&PLUSGSHIFTLOG.PLUSGSHFTLOGENTRY.where=logtype="GENERAL"&oslc.paging=TRUE&oslc.pageSize=100&collectioncount=1&oslc.tlattribute=eventdate&oslc.tlrange=-11M&apikey={{apikey}}
```

the second question really is around how do I transform the data outboud?

thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked much with the REST API, yet, but assuming you can do what you are trying, problems that stand out to me are, (1) `PLUSGSHIFTLOG..where` .. SHIFTLOG should be the top object, so you shouldn't need it in your relationship chain, and (2) `"GENERAL"` .. double-quotes in SQL are used to denote identifiers / column names.. you probably want single quotes around your string literal... `'GENERAL'`

Comment: looking back at the documentation it seems that I should have been referencing the mbo name and relationship name <mbo_name>.<rel_name>.where.  in the documentation the example that they give is the MXPO object structure where the po = MBO name and poline = rel name.  In looking at maximo they both seem to check out.  So I've changed mine to reflect the same.... relationship  LOGENTRIES      keyrecord = :shiftnum.   Using this in the request then PLUSGSHIFTLOG.LOGENTRIES.where.  Still getting the same outcome as before.  I'm new to maximo so there could be glaring problems that I'm not seeing.

Comment: changing the " to ' had no effect on the request.  Same outcome where it is pulling everything back.